# print non ascii text in python

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

I am using python2 and I want to convert the non utf-8 text into readable string. I am trying decode using latin-1 and utf-8 also. But I am getting no success.

This is the string

```
s =  ' Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¿ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â²ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¾ ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â®ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¥Ã¢Â€Â¡ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã¢Â€ÂšÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¦ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¾ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¨ ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â°ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¥Ã¢Â€Â¹ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¥Ã…Â“ ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã¢Â€Â¡ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã¢Â€ÂšÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¦ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¥Ã…Â’ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â°'
```

I tried:

```
s.decode('utf-8')
```

I am getting following output:

```
u' \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xbf\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xb2\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xbe \xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xae\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa5\xc3\xa2\xc2\u20ac\xc2\xa1\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\xa2\xc2\u20ac\xc2\u0161\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xa6\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xbe\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xa8 \xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xb0\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa5\xc3\xa2\xc2\u20ac\xc2\xb9\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa5\xc3\u2026\xc2\u201c \xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\xa2\xc2\u20ac\xc2\xa1\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\xa2\xc2\u20ac\xc2\u0161\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xa6\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa5\xc3\u2026\xc2\u2019\xc3\u0192\xc2 \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xb0'
```

The above output is still non-readable.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first: **you MUST [read this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), no excuse**.

Once done, you'll understand that trying to decode a byte string to unicode without knowing the original encoding is mostly a waste of time.

Second point: this (shortened for readability):

```
u' \xc3\u201a\xc2\xa4\xc3\u201a\xc2\xbf\xc3\u0192\xc2 '
```

is Python's inner representation of the unicode string -  you'd get something similar by displaying the inner representation of your byte string:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = "Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¿ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â²ÃƒÂ"
>>> s # internal representation
'\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa4\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xbf\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82 \xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xa4\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x82\xc2\xb2\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82'
>>> print(s) # readable output
Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¿ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â²ÃƒÂ
```

So your only issue here is confusing the internal representation with the "human-visible" output

Now note that how the string will ultimately be displayed to the user depends on the software doing the rendering (your xterm or equivalent if running python from command line and printing to stdout, your browser if rendering this as part of a server-side generated HTTP response, etc etc) and system settings, all of which are outside Python's responsabilities.

Comment: Well, with some knowledge of exsting codecs, characteristics of language and some heuristics it's often possible to guess the right encoding, which is why the [fixes-text-for-you](https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/) library is such a valuable helper in cases like these. However, the OP's data is unfortunately too badly obfuscated or corrupted for ftfy...

Comment: @lenz yes, there's also UnicodeDammit and a couple other "try and guess" solutions but well, those are all wild guesses...